# Arrays.asList и Collections.addAll не работают с int [] array?

Tags: java

```
int [] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
List list = new ArrayList();
```

вот так привести массив в List могу.

```
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(o-> list.add(o));
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) list.add(arr[i]);
list = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

а так нет:

```
   list = Arrays.asList(arr);
   Collections.addAll(list,arr);
   list = Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

при том что ЦИТАТА: 
Как и следует из документации Arrays.asList: формирует список на основе массива. Массив при этом используется для внутреннего представления списка. Таким образом сохраняется связь между списком и исходным массивом:

1. изменения в массиве отразятся на списке
2. изменения в списке отразятся на массиве
   НО это list = Arrays.asList(arr); бесполезная (censored) т.к. получаю [I@65b54208 а не 1,2,3,4 . получается объект arr поместил в list. спрашивается - где тут преобразование. такое слово даже ниже есть, только (censored) оно не преобразовывает

и ЦИТАТА:
Collections.addAll(ArrayList list, T[] array) — лучший способ преобразовать Array в ArrayList, потому что массив данных копируется в список в виде самостоятельного объекта. А это значит, что исходный массив и результирующий ArrayList будут независимы друг от друга.
ТАКЖЕ (censored) - смотреть выше.

ВОПРОС: везде где гуглю в примерах то стринги то классы(экзы с именами и т.д.). пробую найти ответ на запрос"java array to list"
нашел только

```
 Integer[] spam = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(spam);
```

может я ищу Метод в коллекциях которого не существует. и нужно ввести еще одну операцию массив int в массив Integer??? и нет готового метода это сделать = получается нужно самому написать итерацию или создать новый массив Integer + и затем к нему применить методы из Arrays или Collections, различные варианты с Stream.of(arr) тоже не помогают. вообще не понятно что тут стримится, кажется что ничего.  boxed() есть в Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()  , но почемуто нету в Stream.of(arr). 
p.s. если тема вопроса тупая - то пусть модераторы удаляют,

> кто умеет скройте плиз нижний текст в скрытый разворачивающийся текст.

зачем вообще я это пытаюсь понять везде по форумам массивы примитивов int и т.д. никто совершенно не рассматривает - всюду Object, и String(тот же object), может их вообще не используют по жизни в Java - это как устаревшее и массивы типа int это моветон, а т.к. памяти хватает - то все объявляют массивы (речь не идет о сетах мапах) сразу все в типах Integer Double и т.п, хоть они и занимают в четыре раза больше памяти? и как анекдот: зачем вообще нужно int [] в list загонять в реальных проектах тоже, не знаю. надеюсь со временем станет понятно. нужно это или нет.

Comment: так чем `list = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());` не нравится то?

Comment: [How to convert int\[\] into List<Integer> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1073919/312041)

Comment: Arrays.asList и Collections.addAll зачем нужны к  массивам типа int [] и второе почему boxed() есть в Arrays.stream(arr).boxed() , но почемуто нету в Stream.of(arr). и третье: может знаешь ОНО в работе потом нужно int [] преобразование в коллекции?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что у вас что-то не работает?

Comment: 1 и 3 не работают. не совместимые типы. первый понятно , но и этот List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr)); не работает - просит джинерик и с <Integer> не хочет. в принципе мне и второго хватает. тогда получается что действительно ни Arrays.asList ни Stream.of(arr). с примитивами не работают. и Stream.of(arr). вообще огрызок(половину методов нету) по сравнению с Arrays.stream(arr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы немного запутались.

В зависимости от вашей задачи вам может подойти один из этих способов преобразования массива примитивных интов в список:

```
int [] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

1. `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);`
2. `List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`
3. `List<Integer> list = Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Далее есть один нюанс. `Arrays.asList()` возвращает, согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

> fixed-size list backed by the specified array

Т.е. не обычный `ArrayList`, а такой, который не позволяет добавлять в него новые элементы. Именно по этому у вас не работает такой код:

```
list = Arrays.asList(arr);
Collections.addAll(list,arr); //тут вы пытаетесь в нерасширяемый список добавить его же копию.
```

Это обходят просто - оборачивают нерасширяемый список в `ArrayList` так:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

---

Второй нюанс - вывод в консоль содержимого списка. Т.к. в консоль выводится возвращаемое значение метода `toString` то, если он в к-л классе не переопределён, то может вернуть что-то типа `I@65b54208`. Однако, если вы пройдётесь циклом по списку и выведите каждый его элемент, то увидите, что всё в порядке.

---

По поводу использования примитивов и массивов. В лично моей практике они не используются. У списков и объектных аналогов примитивов больше методов и они гибче. Засим, проще код писать с их использованием. К тому же, если писать не на Java, а на Kotlin, то там вообще примитивов нет.

Да, память можно съэкономить на примитивах, но этим стоит заморачиваться только в особенных случаях. Если вам критично важно экономить байты и микросекунды и не критична красота и удобство кода - то используйте примитивы. Или вообще язык более низкого уровня. Иначе - используйте списки вместо массивов и, соответственно, объектные аналоги примитивов.

Comment: 1 и 3 не работают. не совместимые типы

Comment: первый понятно , но и этот List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr)); не работает - просит джинерик и с <Integer> не хочет. в принципе мне и второго хватает. тогда получается что действительно ни Arrays.asList ни Stream.of(arr). с примитивами не работают. и Stream.of(arr). вообще огрызок(половину методов нету) по сравнению с Arrays.stream(arr)

Comment: за комментарий, как оно по жизни - отдельное спасибо и лайк

Comment: List<Integer> list8 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr1));
            System.out.println(list8.size());
ответ 1 = размер. т.е. там не 4 элемента и ни стрим с sout ни форич не работают - ошибка компилятора

Comment: @Stanislav, да, вполне возможно, что что-то из приведённого не работает)  Поковырял немого код - да, всё плохо. Просто конвертнуть одно в другое что-то не выходит) Вывод - не использовать массивы и примитивы - много боли)